# Pyramid/Apex login example code

Tags: authentication, pyramid, apex

I have a pyramid app that currently uses apex and velruse for authentication. I need to expand this to have "non-social" login capability, i.e. site-specific user login. It looks like apex has most of the capability that I need, but I'm having trouble actually getting it to function.

Are there any tutorials or example code out there of pages using an apex login screen that contains both social and non-social login examples?

PS. I have looked at the apex documentation and the brief example they include there. However, due to the structure of the pyramid app, I have to use custom templates as opposed to the default ones. This seems to cause problems with LoginForms, or I'm just not doing something right.